# How can i change npm command script on the fly?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-scripts

In my `package.json` file i have

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false"
    },
```

how can i change the script command on the fly so at the end i will have

```
"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=true"
```

i know that i can change directly in the package.json but is there some other way with which i can add this ?

or omit that so at the end i will have

```
react-scripts test
```

at the scripts file when i run

`npm run test`

Answer (score 0):

i will relate to the behavior you seek.

assume you have the following script in `package.json`

```sh
"scripts": {
   "test": "react-scripts test"
}
```

you can call it with an argument, such as

```sh
npm test -- --watchAll=false
```

which will be equal to `react-scripts test --watchAll=false`. in the same manner, you can change `false` to `true` in your command.

in my humble opinion, this will be much more straightforward, rather than using other methods. but here are few other methods:

- use an environment variable which exposes your arguments and refer to it within the command in `package.json`. e.g.

  in `package.json`:

  ```sh
  "scripts": {
     "test": "react-scripts test $REACT_OPTS"
  }
  ```

  ```sh
  $ TEST_OPTS="--watchAll=false"
  $ npm test
  ```
- manipulate the script within `package.json`

  ```sh
  cat package.json \
    | jq --arg v 'react-scripts test --watchAll=false' '.scripts.test = $v' \
    | sponge  package.json
  ```

Comment: I know this... But it is not the behaviour that i want.

Comment: @pece: included more options for you and i've updated my answer